# Has there ever been a secret hat that was never awarded?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, secret-hats

I was having a discussion about secret-hat difficulty and it got me wondering.

Has there ever been a secret hat that was so hard (or obscure) to get that it was never awarded?

---

**Edit:**

Since this has never happened, I'm highlighting the following comment from @Shadow Wizard regarding the rarest hat in Winterbash history.

> Flying Tiger, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/Winter-Bash-2015-Hats-Off/): "Flying Tiger was a successor to last year's Red Baron... only 11 were earned (all by different users), making this the rarest hat in the history of Winter Bash!

Comment: Probably not, hats can't hide from the millions of SE users here

Comment: I don't believe we can ever know this as secret hats are secret so no one knows how to get them and if you don't know what secret hats there are you can never know if all of them were ever awarded.

Comment: This information is kept secret.

Answer (score 16):

The Community team makes a post after each WinterBash in which they talk about the hats, including revealing the secret hats.  While only they would know if a hat has ever remained *truly* secret, they have never announced an undiscovered hat in these posts.  It's *possible* they've kept secrets past the end of the bash, but it seems unlikely to me that they wouldn't at least drop a hint ("by the way, there were two hats nobody ever found, so we're going to revamp them for next year -- stay tuned!").

Comment: There was never such a case. And I'm pretty sure we would've said so :)

Comment: @balpha just curious though, what was the hardest secret hat, i.e. the hat with lowest number of users who got it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure, but there's probably answers in the various after-WB blog posts, they were always full of statistics.

Comment: @balpha thanks, found it. Flying Tiger, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/Winter-Bash-2015-Hats-Off/): "Flying Tiger was a successor to last year's Red Baron... only 11 were earned (all by different users), making this the rarest hat in the history of Winter Bash!"